# How can we load all properties located in different property files within same folder?

Tags: java, properties-file

I want to run the proerties file from the whole folder. If the the property is not present in one file, the system should search in the other files in the same folder. How can I achieve this via Properties file in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.Reader-) consecutive calls to `load` will add several properties files.

If you use [ResourceBundle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html), actually a PropertyResourceBundle, one could create ones own ResourceBundle and delegate to the actual properties files.
In order to prevent trying wrong bundles for some requested key, one could preload all properties files, for instance as one large ListResourceBundle.
Or a Map could be used.
The behaviour would change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to search all propertie files one by one. Note that the result may not be unique since two propertie files can contain the same key. It may help to load all propertie files once and put their values inside a single Map.

Answer (score 0):

You can create [Ant Task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html).

Following is an example. See [here for more](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadproperties.html):

```
<loadproperties>
  <file file="file1.properties"/>
  <file file="file2.properties"/>
  <file file="file3.properties"/>
</loadproperties>
```

Comment: I am using Maven, is there any same functionality out there?